# Test Class for Logicless Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that calls another class and doesn't have much code in it aside from this:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

if (Trigger.isBefore) {

 if (Trigger.isInsert) {

  for(Account acc : Trigger.New) {
   accounts.add(acc);
  }

 } 
 if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
 }
 if (Trigger.isDelete) {
 }

} // end isBefore

if(accounts != null) AccountHandler.checkDupes(accounts);
```

All of the logic is in my "AccountHandler" class.  What test methods do I need to write to ensure sufficient test coverage when this class does not have code?

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that this claim is false:

> All of the logic is in my "AccountHandler" class

because you do in fact have logic here that accumulates a list of Accounts. The logic doesn't make a great deal of sense, although I think some of that may be due to the redaction you seem to have performed here. Note though that an allocated list is not going to be `null`, there's no reason to have those empty conditionals if there's no real code present, and you don't need to copy `Trigger.new` if you're not applying any filtering to it.

All that said, it *is* logic, it influences the action of your code, and it needs to be tested.

You need to exercise the trigger functionality in the same way that you would any other logic, except that you cannot call it directly - you perform DML operations in test context to fire it.

You can structure this in a couple of different ways:

1. You can treat it as a unit test verging towards integration testing, by having your test methods perform DML operations that fire the trigger and writing assertions to validate that the expected action is carried out by your handler class.
2. You can be more rigorous about isolating the functionality and apply dependency injection, using a mock handler class. In this approach, your test cases would also perform DML to fire the trigger, but rather than validating the end-to-end action of the trigger and handler, you'd have your mock handler validate that it received the expected call with the expected parameters for the specific trigger event being tested.

With a trigger + handler this straightforward, I probably would just do (1) myself.

Answer (score 2):

Really, unless you're absolutely sure you plan on developing more code, I'd suggest that you just follow [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) and take out all the unnecessary code, reducing your trigger to just:

```
trigger X on Account (before insert) {
  AccountHandler.checkDupes(Trigger.new);
}
```

If you need different event handlers, *then* worry about adding the logic. Prefer using the new switch keyword:

```
trigger X on Account (before insert, ...) {
  switch on Trigger.operationType {
    when BEFORE_INSERT {
      AccountHandler.checkDupes(Trigger.new);
    }
  }
}
```

It's far easier to read in the long run.

That said, it doesn't matter if there's 1 line or 1,000, you need to test your business logic. That means writing a test that covers as much code as possible, and, more importantly, verifies all the business logic works.

You'll need to insert a handful of records, make sure that some records are blocked.